# Как удалять метаданные удаленного файла в системе FAT32

Tags: c++, fat32

Мне нужен алгоритм для удаления метаданных удаленного файла в системе FAT32. Т.е пользователь удалят файл, заполненный псевдослучайными символами. Проблема в том, что программы для восстановления находят имя удаленного файла, а мне нужно его в идеале удалить, либо сделать так, чтобы имя было похоже хотя бы на "АААА.АААА".

Пока пытался разобраться, написал такой код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    //Путь к диску U:, его открытие     L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0\\Partition2";
    
    //Путь к разделу через физический диск
    const wchar_t* partitionU = L"\\\\.\\U:";

    HANDLE hDisk = CreateFile(partitionU, 
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    if (hDisk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
    //****************************************




    // Получаем информацию о геометрии диска
    DISK_GEOMETRY diskGeometry;
    DWORD bytesReturned;

    if (DeviceIoControl(hDisk, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, NULL, 0, &diskGeometry, sizeof(diskGeometry), &bytesReturned, NULL)) {
        // Выводим информацию о геометрии диска
        std::cout << "DISK INFO\n*************************************\n";
        std::cout << "Тип диска: " << diskGeometry.MediaType << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Секторов на треке: " << diskGeometry.SectorsPerTrack << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Число головок: " << diskGeometry.TracksPerCylinder << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Общее число секторов: " << diskGeometry.Cylinders.QuadPart * diskGeometry.TracksPerCylinder * diskGeometry.SectorsPerTrack << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Ошибка при получении информации о геометрии диска. Код ошибки: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "*****************************************\n\n\n" << std::endl;
    //*******************************************




    //Проверка атрибутов
    const wchar_t* diskPath = L"\\\\.\\U:";
    DWORD attributes = GetFileAttributes(diskPath);
    if (attributes != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {
        // Проверка наличия атрибута FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY
        if (attributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY) {
            std::cout << "Диск доступен только для чтения." << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Диск доступен для записи." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Ошибка при получении атрибутов диска. Код ошибки: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        
    }
    //******************

    //чтение данных с байта 4 194 304
    if (SetFilePointer(hDisk, 4867072, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER) {
        std::cerr << "Ошибка установки указателя: ";
        return GetLastError();
    }
   
    byte buffer[1024];
    DWORD dwRead;

    if (ReadFile(hDisk, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &dwRead, NULL)) {
        std::cout << "Прочитано байт:" << dwRead << std::endl;
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwRead; ++i) {
            std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(buffer[i]) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Ошибка при чтении: " <<GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    //*********************************
   



    //************запись данных в байт
    //LARGE_INTEGER liMove;
    //liMove.QuadPart = 0x004005a0;

    byte* pointer = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(4867072);
    LARGE_INTEGER largeInt;
    largeInt.QuadPart = reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pointer);

    if (!SetFilePointerEx(hDisk, largeInt, NULL, FILE_BEGIN)) { //file_begin - от начала файла
        std::cerr << "Ошибка установки указателя: ";
        return GetLastError();
    }

    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    //const char dataToWrite[] = "\xd2";
    byte byte = 0xAA;
    if (WriteFile(hDisk, &byte, sizeof(byte) -1, &dwBytesWritten, NULL)) {
        std::cout << "Данные успешно записаны. Байтов записано: " << dwBytesWritten << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Ошибка при записи данных в файл. Код ошибки: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    //***************************************
    CloseHandle(hDisk);
    return 0;
}
```

Заметил такие странности:

1. Когда я пытаюсь обратиться к любому байту - выдается ошибка "Неверно переданные аргументы".
2. Когда я обращаюсь к байту, с которого начинается файл - тогда все нормально, все читается (Самое интересное что этих проблем нет у NTFS. Т.е указатель можно ставить куда угодно, а в FAT - только на начало)
3. В статьях написан примерно такой код, как у меня, и везде написано что байты перезаписываются прям на диске. У меня же это не работает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении копать вообще?

Comment: "*чтобы имя было похоже хотя бы на "АААА.АААА"*" — ну так переименуйте перед удалением. А до того еще и перезапишите.

Comment: @Harry , проблема в том, что программы восстановления видят это самое "АААА.АААА" и его предыдущее имя. Стало быть в файловой системе нужно затирать то место с именем, а не просто переименовывать его

Comment: Взял флешку с FAT32, создал файл, переименовал, даже не затирая. Взял упомянутую Recuva. Видит только последнее имя, с затертым первым символом. Кстати, при восстановлении внутри оказалась полная ерунда...

Comment: Вот да, непомню чтобы в формате FAT32 было хранение истории переименований файлов. Если это только какой-то отдельный журнал операционной среды. Но тогда и запись на прямую в FAT не поможет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. FAT требует полностью переписывать сектор, так что в алгоритме нет ошибок, кроме указания в нём байта не являющегося началом сектора

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы программы восстановления удаленных не находили ваш файл, вам нужно удалять соответствующую запись в таблице FAT. Для этого нужен низкоуровневый доступ. Да и не имея опыта можно очень много дел наворотить.

Смысл FAT в том что в таблице лежит название файла, его аттрибуты и указатель, который указывает на начало файла. При удалении же файла средвами операционной среды (или когда вы его удаляете из своего приложения) в таблице FAT просто меняется признак, что файл удаленный. Больше ничего не меняется. И пока на это место в таблице не будет записана информация о каком-то другом файле - удаленный файл можно восстановить. И восстановится он корректно в том случае если не была проивзедена запись в те блоки на диске, которые он занимал.

Если же у вас задача состояит в том чтобы предотвратить восстановелние файла, то самое простое - это переписать соержимое файла. Т.е. открываете файл на запись и записываете в него любые символы в том количестве, сколько было байт в этом файле. Обычно просто пишут 0 и все. После этого даже если файл восстановят, то его содержимое будет недоступно (бесполезно).

Если нужно еще и имя файла скрыть, то тут тоже проще  переименовать его, а потом уже удалить.

Все это делается стандартными средствами С/С++. И не надо лезть на низкий уровень. Да и риски что-то попутно сломать очень малы.

Comment: Даааа, это все реализовано уже, файл при попытке восстановления получается ломанный, но проблема в том, что программы восстановления выдают оригинальное название файла и его переименование в "АААА.АААА". А мне нужно чтобы след присутствия этого файла на диске вообще не оставался. Т.е чтобы либо его вообще не было, либо чтобы только "АААА.АААА" осталось, потому что например если файл назывался "секретный файл", то Recuva даст пользователю что был файл с именем "секретный файл" и что на его месте был записан "АААА.АААА", а этого быть не должно

Comment: Ну попробуйте переименовать файл несколько раз. Сначала в AAA.AAA потом в BBB.BBB и только потом удалить.

Comment: Да ёмоё, говорю же: хоть запереименуйся, но какая-нибудь Recuva покажет что был файл "asdf.asd", а он записан на месте "секретный файл.txt".
Потому и говорю что мне нужно каким-то макаром чистить метаданные напрямую в файловой системе

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что FAT32 хранит всю историю переименований одного и того же файла?

Comment: Не осмелюсь утверждать, но похоже именно на это. Иначе как объяснить такую картину: файл забивается чем попало, переименовывается от A до Z, удаляется, а при восстановлении программа восстановления пишет что файл AAA.AAA найден на месте "секретный файл.txt" и его можно восстановить (битый, само-собой), и ниже пишет что был файл "секретный файл.txt". Откуда-то же он достаёт эту информацию.
В общем, нужен алгоритм, затирающий этот след

Comment: FAT32 не хранит историю. Историю вероятней всего хранит операционная система. Т.е. если это Windows - значит у вас включенно журналирование всех операций. И программа восстановления берет информацию не с диска, а из этого журнала. Возможно ли его очистить и главное как - вот тут уже не знаю. Но знаю что прямая запись в диск, или что вы там хотели сделать в своем первоначальном вопросе - это вам не поможет.

Comment: Я разобрался с таблицей, путём редактирования в WinHex мне удалось добиться чтобы программы восстановления не видели изначального названия файла. Теперь вопрос стоит в другом: почему ОС блокирует мне доступ к файловой системе? Запускаю от админа студию.